# Adding new lines to a pre-existing text file with a console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a program that has pre-existing items in an inventory stored in a text file and the user can increase the quantity of each item. I am trying to add code where I can have the user add a completely new item that was not previously in the text file via command-line input.

This is the code that I have for loading my file and converting each variable to a specific data type to make sure the file loads:

```
public void LoadDb(string fname)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Loading File {0}", fname);

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fname);
                int count = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadLine());
                inventories = new Inventory[count];

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    string[] line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    string name = line[0];
                    int code = Convert.ToInt32(line[1]);
                    string description = line[2];
                    int stock = Convert.ToInt32(line[3]);

                    inventories[i] = new Inventory(name, code, description, stock);
                }

                sr.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("{0} records loaded.", count);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not open file: ", exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

My text file has the length at the very top with a single number, followed by lines of my inventory with the following headers (they are in another script) "Name" "Code" "Description" "Stock":

```
6
apple tools,111,temp desc,6
pear tools,222,temp desc,5
mango,333,temp desc,6
orange,444,temp desc,7
strawberry,555,temp desc,1
peach,666,temp desc,2
```

I have tried Console.Write(); with StreamWriter and also AppendText to be able to add more lines but because I already have a fixed item length (the 6 in the text file), do I need to redo my entire code here?

Comment: You need to rewrite the entire file. I would recommend reading the initial count first, then reading the items into a collection, then comparing the count you read to the collection's `Count` to validate. You can then add a new item to the collection and then write out the entire collection, preceded by the collection's `Count`. That's the logic you should follow, so formalise that into an algorithm and then write code to implement that algorithm. Some of the code you already have will still be relevant.

Comment: You can add a line to a file with `File.AppendAllLines()`. If you want to modify your file, you can do: `using var fs = new File().OpenWrite("fname"); fs.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(count + 1), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(count + 1).Length);`
But I would recommend to rewrite entierly your file to avoid mistakes